# My simple navigation bar won't lay horizontal in my rails app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, view

I have looked everywhere to resolve this problem, and I'm coming here as a last resort.
I can not get my navigation links to display horizontally in my rails 4 app, and I have tried inline styling, external stylesheets etc.. This code came directly from a source that does display the links horizontally so I am very confused as to why I can't properly replicate it.  Thanks.

Here is my application layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>H4TF</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                       "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "H4TF", '#', id: "logo" %>
      <nav style="display:inline;">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "About", controller: "welcome", action: "about", id:@about    %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Store",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Blog", '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS, I can only imagine that you're missing something. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6xs2b9j/), and you'll see how I was able to make a list display horizontally.

This is the CSS:

```
.nav li { float: left; list-style-type: none; }
```